# Issue in sending email to a group email using java mail

Tags: java, email

As subject is self explanatory - I am facing issue in sending email to a group email using java mail.

I have gone through through several blogs & articles which are of no help & does not have a precise answer or hangs in middle.

Can you please help. Here is my mail class for you. My mail is going to have a link to ftp location & a text file as an attachment.

To separate the issue i tried to send a simple mail to the group as well but that didn't help either.

I tried to find answers in places like java-forums.org & Stack overflow but found no luck.

I appreciate your quality time & help in providing an insight to the issue.

To explain the issue better-

My Automation framework when completes the execution of test cases, it sends a mail to me with the link to execution report & a log file as an attachment. Now the audience for the report has expanded & we need to send the mail to a group email address.

When I set the email (to say group.email@company.com) none of the users in the group receives the mail. Where as if I send the email to my email address or anyone else email address it works.

I get no logs or error for this & so I am not able to understand the issue correctly.

An insight from the experts will help in understanding the issue.

Thanks in advance.
Akshat

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class ReportMail {

private MimeMessage message = null;
private Session emailSession = null;
private MimeBodyPart textPart = null;
private ArrayList<MimeBodyPart> attachmentArray = null;

public void sendMailer(String mailToId, String string, String mailServer1,
        int mailPort, String mailAdmin) {
    Properties mailProperties = null;
    mailProperties = new Properties();

    String adminEmailId = mailAdmin;
    String mailServer = mailServer1;
    mailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    //mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", mailServer);
    mailProperties.put("mail.from", adminEmailId);
    mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", mailPort);
    mailProperties.put("mail.to", mailToId);


    try {
        emailSession = Session.getInstance(mailProperties);
        emailSession.setDebug(false);

        message = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
        textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachmentArray = new ArrayList<MimeBodyPart>(2);
        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, mailToId);
        message.setSubject(string);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(adminEmailId));

        setContent("<a href=\"file://tambe3/report/emailable-report.html\" target=\"_blank\">PCM Automation Report</a>");
        //setContent("test123");
        sendEMail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    try {
        textPart.setContent(content, "text/html");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean sendEMail() throws Exception {
    try {
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
        for (int i = 0; i < attachmentArray.size(); i++)
            mp.addBodyPart(attachmentArray.get(i));

        /********************
         * 
         */
        // Part two is attachment
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart.setText("Below is the link for the Test Automation report as link & attached Log file. PFA.");
        //mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        String filename = "logfile.log";     //C:\workspacePCMSanity\PCMSanity\logfile.log
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        /**
         * 
         */
        message.setContent(mp);

        Transport transport = emailSession.getTransport();
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw e;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the group email expanded to all the individuals on the list?  You need to have that code involved in handling your mail.

Comment: Thanks Anderson. I was wondering how come other email application like Gmail or Outlook itself will be handling it !! It should be as simple as sending a mail. do you know the root cause behind the issue. Though I will try you suggestion.

Comment: Expanding the list works..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't know whether an email address is for a single user or a group. 
Probably the issue with SMTP Server.

Comment: Hi, to elaborate this a bit more for you, when the test team get the bits to test, an email get floated automatically from Electric Commander to a group email address about the build generation. I guess with this in reference you may be able to explain your point. I believe there must be a way to address this issue. Your expert advice will be more than a help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Agree Sudz, I got you point.

I better keep it simple & add recipients to  `code`MimeMessage obj `code` like below- 

`code`MimeMessage message =  new MimeMessage(emailSession);
message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "username1@comp.com");
message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "username2@comp.com");`code`

or rather keep all the recipients in an array & pass them to   `code`addRecipients(RecipientType, address)`code`  method.

Comment: Yes Akshat you can try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

In **Microsoft Exchange Server** there is a special group address setting option **Require that all senders are authenticated**. When an unknown user is used as a sender, such an email is rejected. You can either send emails in the name of real user or enable this option. In the latter case the group address is opened to spam.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124405%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx